# Python3 LDAP query to get name and email of a specific group

Tags: python, ldap

I would like to get the users' name and email of a specific group when querying an LDAP server using ldap3 Python library.
I have been trying the following command, but I am not getting also the email address.

```
c.search(search_base=LDAP_BASE,search_filter=("(&(objectclass=group)(cn=test-group))"),attributes=["*"])
```

Any idea how to get have this filter to retrieve the desired data?
This query is not retrieving also the email address.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everyone needs the same query, here is the answer:

```
# Firstly find out the DN associated with LDAP group
c.search(base_dn, '(sAMAccountName="test-group")',
                    search_scope=SUBTREE, attributes=['distinguishedName', 'member'])
dn_json = json.loads(c.response_to_json())
distinguished_name = dn_json["entries"][0]["attributes"]["distinguishedName"]

# Retrieve data based on DN
c.search(base_dn, '(&(objectclass=user)(memberOf={}))'.format(distinguished_name),
                    attributes=["givenName", "sn", "mail"])
user_data = json.loads(c.response_to_json())
for index in range(len(user_data["entries"])):
    first_name = user_data["entries"][index]["attributes"]["givenName"]
    surname = user_data["entries"][index]["attributes"]["sn"]
    mail = user_data["entries"][index]["attributes"]["mail"]
```